# Loop only displaying last item correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of link that I'm using to display a list of articles. Each of the links is entered into a textarea when creating the post.

The last item of the array displays correctly while the first three pull the current page title for the article title and the current user logged in as the author. Both title and author are incorrect.

Any ideas?

$urls Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://localhost:8888/2013/10/custom-toothbrush-six-second-cleaning.html 
    [1] => http://localhost:8888/2013/10/climate-change-global-warming-al-gore.html 
    [2] => http://localhost:8888/2013/10/custom-toothbrush-six-second-cleaning.html 
    [3] => http://localhost:8888/2013/10/climate-change-global-warming-al-gore.html 
    )
```

Here is the PHP code

```
 $urls=explode(PHP_EOL, get_field('publishing_articles'));
 foreach($urls as $url){    
    $id=url_to_postid($url);
    $the_title=get_the_title($id);
    $author_id=get_post_field('post_author',$id);
    $author_displayname=get_the_author_meta('display_name',$author_id);
    $author_nicename=get_the_author_meta('user_nicename',$author_id);

    echo '<li>'.$id;
    echo '<a href="/author/'.$author_nicename.'" title="'.$the_title.'"><img width="50" src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/'.$author_id.'.jpg" alt="'.$author_displayname.'"/></a>';
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$the_title.'">'.$the_title.'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
 }
```

And the HTML Output

```
 <li>0<a href="/author/admin" title="The Future Of Light"><img width="50" src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/362.jpg" alt="admin"/></a><a href="http://localhost:8888/2013/10/custom-toothbrush-six-second-cleaning.html" title="The Future Of Light">The Future Of Light</a></li>
 <li>0<a href="/author/admin" title="The Future Of Light"><img width="50" src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/362.jpg" alt="admin"/></a><a href="http://localhost:8888/2013/10/climate-change-global-warming-al-gore.html" title="The Future Of Light">The Future Of Light</a></li>
 <li>0<a href="/author/admin" title="The Future Of Light"><img width="50" src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/362.jpg" alt="admin"/></a><a href="http://localhost:8888/2013/10/custom-toothbrush-six-second-cleaning.html" title="The Future Of Light">The Future Of Light</a></li>
 <li>210664<a href="/author/daniela-walker" title="How Al Gore Is Making Global Warming Personal"><img width="50" src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/384.jpg" alt="Daniela Walker"/></a><a href="http://localhost:8888/2013/10/climate-change-global-warming-al-gore.html" title="How Al Gore Is Making Global Warming Personal">How Al Gore Is Making Global Warming Personal</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you post what the outputted HTML looks like

Comment: Is the correct `$id` being displayed in each case?

Comment: What is in URLS?  You are probably assigning arrays by reference rather than value...  More code.

Comment: The array on top is $urls. I changed the title to clarify.

Comment: Is `get_field()` an Advanced Custom Fields API function? It kinda sounds familiar.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure `$urls` contains what you expect? If you `print_f($urls)` after `explode()` what would it show?

Comment: Right, not shown here, I used print_f right after explode()

Comment: Last question, I promise :) Is the above code executed before or after init?

Comment: not sure, after init?

Comment: Well, is it part of an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was far less involved than I thought. I didn't trim the lines that were building the $id array. In addition, I have fixed the author functions per geomagas suggestions.

```
 $urls=explode(PHP_EOL, get_field('publishing_articles'));

 foreach($urls as $url){    

    $id=url_to_postid(trim($url));

    $the_title=get_the_title($id);
    $author_id=get_post_field('post_author',$id);
    $author_url=get_the_author_meta('user_nicename',$author_id);
    $author_name=get_the_author_meta('display_name',$author_id);

    $output.='<li>';
    $output.='<a class="author" href="/author/'.$author_url.'" title="More Articles By '.$author_name.'"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/authors/'.$author_id.'.jpg" alt="'.$author_name.'" onerror="author_img_error(this);" /></a>';
    $output.='<a class="link" href="'.$url.'" title="'.$the_title.'">'.$the_title.'</a>';
    $output.='</li>';
 }
 echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `get_the_author_meta()` returns meta about the current, logged-in user if a userid is not specified. Which means that you're using a `NULL` `$author_id` as a parameter. `get_the_title()` has similar behaviour concerning the current post resp. Which means that `$id` is `NULL` too.

This can only mean that `url_to_postid()` returns a `NULL` id.

The above in turn means that `$urls` is not initialized as expected.

And `get_field()` is the cause of that. As with all [ACF](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields) API calls, it needs to be called *after* init (ie in an action handler).

See also: [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-get_field-intermittently-returning-false-after-acf-341-342-update).

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I'm still completely confused by calling something after init...I tried add_action('wp_head', 'get_field'); but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The `wp_head` event runs after `init`, yes. [Here's a refernece of the action sequence during a typical request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). But I didn't mean you should call `get_fied()` alone, but rather _your whole procedure (that includes a call to `get_field()`)_ i.e. the code you posted.